# HttpClient PostAsync to WebApi - returning 500, but no exception thrown)

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making a call to a web api service like this:

```
var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/api/values", new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "b"),}))
                     .Result;
```

Result is a

> "500 internal server error"

No exception is thrown (even though I've set VS to Break when CLR exceptions are thrown)

I there any way I can force VS to bubble up the underlying exception?

Comment: The error may come from earlier in the pipeline, even before managed code has run. Is there anything in the event viewer? If not, you may want to route your traffic through a proxy like Fiddler, sometimes there are details of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no underlying exception, that's why you can't bubble it up.  However, if you want to create one you can call

```
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

If the response code is a 4xx or 5xx then it will throw.

Comment: I know I can throw an exception with response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode, but I'm trying to figure out what is causing the 500 error in the first place... None of my breakpoints in my handlers are hit etc...

Comment: @Alex  Ahhhh, you want to know what the error is on the server side!  One thing you can do is install the ASP.NET tracing.  The other trick that sometimes helps is to get access to the response message and call response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait()  That will cause the serialization to be done earlier when you can still catch any errors that it throws.

Comment: I would recommend elmah instead, much simpler to install and comes with really nice UI